# Quicktime 10 - export in original size, not 4k, 1080p, 720p etc?

Tags: video, quicktime, macos

I do a lot of non full size screen recordings, e.g., they could be small such as 320x240 or in completely non-standard sizes and proportions like 1500x300. I want to save them using HEVC (rather than the default H.264).

In QTP HEVC is only available using File -> Export but that way I can only use a couple of standard dimensions (4k, 1080p, 720p and 480p).

How can I use both HEVC and a non-standard format in QTP10?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to export in any other sizes other than 4K, 1080P, 720P or 480P, according to this post [here](https://support.apple.com/zh-tw/guide/quicktime-player/export-movies-qtp20e395859/mac) (it's in Mandarin, but I translated it) You could, however, export it in a higher resolution (such as 4K or 1080P) and then use another program to save it in your preferred recording.

Why do you need these strangely sized videos, by the way?

Comment: Because they are screen recordings. I only record as much of the screen as I need.

Comment: @d-b ok. that explains it

Comment: @d-b Do you have any other programs that you use, that could stretch it?

Comment: Why would I want to stretch it?

Comment: @d-b to stretch it back into it's original size, after quicktime exports it in a different aspect ratio